# Get multiple strings at ant

Tags: ant

I have for example the js file containing these lines:

```
<script defer src="/js/libs/ui.achtung.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/libs/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>
<script defer src="/js/libs/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
```

I need to concatenate these files at one and place a link to newly created file here replacing existing scripts.

So the algorithm is a) read lines with scripts b) concatenate all scripts to one c) replace script links to only one

I cant find a decision to read multiple lines to place each of them to separate property or so.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to replace the script elements in the files? I do not see the point of concatenating everything from different files only to be replaced by one thing. Also what is the link? The src attribute?

Comment: I want to read all strings where <script> is placed, find all these js files in filesystem, copy them all to a folder, concatenate and minify them all to a single file "script.js", then replace above strings with this new file <script src="/somefolder/script.js">.

Comment: And why exactly do you want to do this with ant? It can be done but other scripting tools/languages can do it easier.

Answer (score 0):

To read multiple lines, have a look at:
[Ant: get multiple matches with propertyregex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939485/ant-get-multiple-matches-with-propertyregex)

The example there extract

```
ABC
ABCD
ABCE
```

out of

```
test.ABC.test
test.ABCD.test
test.ABCE.test
```

with

```
<target name="test">
    <loadfile property="record" srcFile="./index.html">
        <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <containsregex pattern=".*test\.([^\.]*)\.test.*" replace="\1"/>
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <echo message="${record}" />
</target>
```