# Ant: get multiple matches with propertyregex

Tags: ant

I have these (sample) lines in a HTML-file:

```
test.ABC.test
test.ABCD.test
test.ABCE.test
```

And this Ant `propertyregex`:

```
<loadfile property="getRecords" srcFile="./index.html"/>
<propertyregex property="record" input="${getRecords}" regexp="test\.([^\.]*)\.test" select="\1" casesensitive="true" override="true" global="true" />
<echo message="${record}" />
```

The result is just

```
ABC
```

But I'd like to get all matches. How can I get

```
ABC
ABCD
ABCE
```

as result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the propertyregex problem, but this works (without ant-contrib):

```
<target name="test">
    <loadfile property="record" srcFile="./index.html">
        <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <containsregex pattern=".*test\.([^\.]*)\.test.*" replace="\1"/>
            </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
    <echo message="${record}" />
</target>
```